# How to pass 2-D vector to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

If it is passed, is it passed by value or by reference?

```
void printMatrix(vector<vector<int>> *matrix);

...

vector<vector<int>> matrix(3, vector<int>(3,0));
printMatrix(&matrix1);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since your function declaration:

```
void printMatrix(vector< vector<int> > *matrix)
```

specifies a pointer, it is essentially passed by reference. However, in C++, it's better to avoid pointers and pass a reference directly:

```
void printMatrix(vector< vector<int> > &matrix)
```

and

```
printMatrix(matrix1); // Function call
```

This looks like a normal function call, but it is passed by reference as indicated in the function declaration. This saves you from unnecessary pointer dereferences.

Answer (score 3):

Why not passing just the 2d vector?

```
void printMatrix(vector < vector<int> > matrix)
{
    cout << "[";
    for(int i=0; i<matrix.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "[" << matrix[i][0];
        for(int j=0; j<matrix[0].size(); j++)
        {
            cout  << ", " << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << "]" << endl;
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

---

```
vector < vector<int> > twoDvector;
vector<int> row(3,2);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    twoDvector.push_back(row);
}

printMatrix(twoDvector);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you're creating it wrong.

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix1(3, vector<int>(3,0));
```

You can pass by value or by reference, or by pointer(not recommended).  If you're passing to a function that doesn't change the contents, you can either pass by value, or by const reference.  I would prefer const reference, some people think the "correct" way is to pass by value.

```
void printMatrix(const vector<vector<int>> & matrix);

// or
void printMatrix(vector<vector<int>> matrix);

// to call
printMatrix(matrix1);
```

Comment: Don't forget a space in the nested template, i.e. `vector<vector<int> >`, otherwise some compilers will complain about invalid right shifts.

Comment: I'll just use your comment as a note to that effect.  But are there any relevant compilers where this is still an issue?