# Segmentation fault while passing 2d vector of chars in to a function

Tags: c++11

I want to pass a variable which is of type `vector<vector<char>> p` into another function declared as `void foo(vector<vector<char>> &var)`. To pass `p` into `foo` I simply did `foo(p)`. While doing so I get the following error

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<std::vector<char> >) (std::vector<std::vector<char> >&)’
```

I have followed the discussion given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061128/how-to-pass-2-d-vector-to-a-function-in-c)!

**Update**

Now I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. I am attaching a simpler version of the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class foo{
  private:
    vector<vector<char>> b;
  public:
    foo(vector<vector<char>> &n){
      vector<vector<char>> b(n);
    }
    void print_foo() {
      for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << b[i][j];
          }
          cout << endl;
      }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char pp[4][4] = {
    {'1', '1', '1', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '0', '0'},
    {'1', '0', '0', '0'},
    {'1', '0', '0', '1'},
  };

  vector<vector<char>> p;
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    vector<char> m_row;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      m_row.push_back(p[i][j]);
    }
    p.push_back(m_row);
  }

  foo a(p);
  a.print_foo();
}
```

Comment: Please, show your code.

Comment: Include the full error message (including any additional detail lines) that the compiler gives you.

Comment: I have provided the code that I am working with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
m_row.push_back(p[i][j]);
```

You have mistyped `pp` as `p`.

Instead, use this:

```
m_row.push_back(pp[i][j]);
```

According to current code, it won't print the matrix correctly. Why? Because of this:

```
foo(vector<vector<char>> &n) {
    vector<vector<char>> b(n);
}
```

This code creates a local object `b` which will die after it goes out of scope.

```
foo(vector<vector<char>> &n) {
    vector<vector<char>> b(n); // local object created
} // b dies here
```

Instead, you must do this:

```
foo(vector<vector<char>> &n): b(n) {
}
```

**Final Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class foo{
  private:
    vector<vector<char>> b;
  public:
    foo(vector<vector<char>> &n): b(n) { }
    void print_foo() {
      for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << b[i][j];
          }
          cout << endl;
      }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char pp[4][4] = {
    {'1', '1', '1', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '0', '0'},
    {'1', '0', '0', '0'},
    {'1', '0', '0', '1'},
  };

  vector<vector<char>> p;
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    vector<char> m_row;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      m_row.push_back(pp[i][j]);
    }
    p.push_back(m_row);
  }

  foo a(p);
  a.print_foo();
}
```

Comment: And this is yet another example why one should use meaningful names for their variables.

Comment: Doing `b =n` does not print anything either. When I check `b.size()` it prints `0`. Any idea why?