# Global variable is not updating when given as argument to function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, global-variables

I am declaring a global variable, `first_clauses`:

```
vector<vector<int>> first_clauses; //clauses for first iteartion
```

Now, `cnf_transformation` is one of the functions of the program:

```
    void cnf_transformation(vector<vector<string>> gates, vector<vector<int>> first_clauses)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gates.size(); i++)
        {
            if (gates[i][1] == "AND" || gates[i][1] == "and")
            {
                vector<int> cl;
                cl.push_back(-1 * umap_toInt[gates[i][2] + "_a_1"]);
                cl.push_back(-1 * umap_toInt[gates[i][3] + "_a_1"]);
                cl.push_back(umap_toInt[gates[i][0] + "_a_1"]);
                first_clauses.push_back(cl);
                cl.clear();
                cl.push_back(umap_toInt[gates[i][2] + "_a_1"]);
                cl.push_back(-1 * umap_toInt[gates[i][0] + "_a_1"]);
                first_clauses.push_back(cl);
                cl.clear();
//many more lines are there
}
```

I want to push some required data into the global variable first_clauses. So, I am calling `cnf_transformation` and my second argument is `first_clauses`:

```
cnf_transformation(gates, first_clauses);
```

Now, when I print the `first_clauses` data structure inside my function, it is actually storing data but, after coming out of the function, my global variable `first_clauses` is not updated. I am still learning C++. Please guide me.

Comment: Did you mean to pass `first_clauses` by reference?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] as text, not image. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you mean some mystical global variable `first_clause` or the parameter `first_clauses` that you pass by value, thus you only push to a copy of it and the original remains unchanged? One of your edits showed it as being passed by reference, please clarify.

Comment: @churill the global variable I declared is not updating, I tried passing by reference also, by reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061128/how-to-pass-2-d-vector-to-a-function-in-c. But passing by reference also not working.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux please see my last comment.

Comment: @Slava I replaced the image with text.

Comment: Your code shows neither any global variables, nor any variable named "first_clause". Maybe read it again and check if those are just typos. And maybe clarify on your understanding of global variable, it may not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @churill I have declared the global variable first_clauses.

Comment: @churill inside the function, the pushing is happening,but its not adding in the actual global variable first_clauses.

Comment: @churill I have printed the first_clause inside the function, and it actually storing the datas, but global variable first_clauses remain unchanged.

Comment: No, you have _no_ global variable. `first_clauses` (with s at the end, in contrast to your question) is a function parameter and no global variable. And you need to pass it as reference to modify it.

Comment: Its working now, modified first_clauses.push_back(cl); with  ::first_clauses.push_back(cl);

Comment: @churill please see my last comment. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Good you solved it, but it exposes a design weakness you should adress (global variable are considered bad practice).

Comment: @Slava Please open this question. I solved it. I will share the answer. It will help others.

Comment: You still did not provide [mcve] so your question is still useless for others.

Comment: I highly recommend `transform` your text to all upper or all lower case before comparing.  As is, you are missing some possible combinations:  "And", "ANd", "aNd", etc.

Comment: @Slava I have modified it to be more comprehensible, please review it, and suggest some changes if possible